# ros can't find OpenCV , the path /usr/local/

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ros, catkin

I am working with ros and OpenCV. I installed  OpenCV in the default path `/usr/local`, but when I build programs with catkin_make in my workstation, it shows Project `cv_bridge` specifies `/usr/include/opencv` as an include dir, which is not found.

Can you show me what can I do to solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [opencv2_catkin](https://github.com/ethz-asl/opencv2_catkin) package that automatically finds and links your package to OpenCV. As per the Readme, just add the following dependency to your own package:

```
<build_depend>opencv2_catkin</build_depend>
```

You would also need to download [catkin_simple](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_simple) to use `opencv2_catkin`.

Answer (score 0):

I found you said you use catkin_make, so in new version of ROS, opencv and pcl are no longer integrate in ROS, so you need find you opencv yourself. For example, in your workspace, the **CMakeLists.txt** file, you should add something like `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`, and add include dir and libs to your project. If you also have problems, please paste your details of errors.