# How to link opencv to ROS indigo (catkin) with CMake (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: opencv, compilation, ros

Am so far not able to use cv_bridge. Am getting this compilation error

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake:106 (message):
  Project 'cv_bridge' specifies '/usr/include/opencv' as an include dir,
  which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '/opt/ros/indigo//usr/include/opencv'.  Ask the maintainer ..
```

May be the problem in my CMake (...?)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(XY)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
cv_bridge
image_transport
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
)

#set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/lib/opencv")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc highgui PATHS /home/polar/soft/lib/opencv/opencv-3.1.0/cmake)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

if(OpenCV_FOUND)
# include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("\n\n OpenCV found!!!! \n\n")   
endif()
```

Any idea on the cause of the problem and how to solve it please? 
I was using ROS fuerte in the past and never experience such problems....

Comment: did you add it to `package.xml` accordingly ? `<build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>`   `<run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>`

Comment: yes. In fact I specified the need of cv_bridge when creating the package

Comment: weird, try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613363/ros-cant-find-opencv-the-path-usr-local

Comment: Does not seem providing a solution to the problem

Comment: it seems like you are trying the new OpenCV 3.1 with ros indigo. did you try using [openCV3](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3) or did you install it yourself ? maybe it's better using `ros-indigo-opencv3`. I didn't try it myself though !

Comment: I installed opencv 3.1 myslef. In fact I just reinstalled following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726768/opencv-3-0-trouble-with-installation

Comment: Just to point out that previously removed and re-installed ros-indigo.... maybe this is the source of the problem.. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I modified file `/opt/ros/indigo/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake`

I changed

```
set(cv_bridge_FOUND_CATKIN_PROJECT TRUE)

if(NOT "include;/usr/include/opencv;/usr/include " STREQUAL " ")
  set(cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS "")
  set(_include_dirs "include;/usr/include/opencv;/usr/include")
```

to

```
set(cv_bridge_FOUND_CATKIN_PROJECT TRUE)
if(NOT "include;/usr/local/include/opencv" STREQUAL " ")
  set(cv_bridge_INCLUDE_DIRS "")
  set(_include_dirs "/usr/local/include/opencv;/usr/include;/usr/local/include")
```

In fact I just changed `usr/include` to `/usr/local/include`. This solved my problem. But I do not think it the correct way to do (?).

Comment: I get an error that the make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so.2.4.8', needed by `/home/johann/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libimage_converter.so'.  Stop. after following your steps, have you had anything similar?

Comment: I had this issue a time ago. I ended up wiping out everything and reinstalling opencv. Have you installed both opencv from source and that coming with ros (full desktop)? If so, remove ros and uninstall the standalone opencv (with sudo make uninstall, make clean, etc..). Reinstall ROS and opencv again. BUT NOTE, install opencv with `./configure --prefix=DIFF_PATH`, where  `DIFF_PATH` sould be different from `/usr/*` so as to avoid any system confusion. Eg. I usually set `DIFF_PATH=~/soft/lib/opencv/build`. Hope this helps.